# didEnterRegion Method only Fires for Most Recent Region

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use the iOS didEnterRegion method in my app. I have a tableView that passes the user to a profileViewController. In the viewDidLoad method of the profileViewController I have a set of latitude and longitude coordinates that I store as a region, then I start monitoring for that region.

This code works, but the didEnterRegion method only fires for the last profile that was loaded. For example, if I look at profile A and start monitoring the region for profile A, then I look at profile B, the didEnterRegion will only fire if I enter the region for profile B.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong? Thanks!

**Here is the code that is in the viewDidLoad method of the profileViewController:**

```
NSString *latOne = placeLatitude;
NSString *lngOne = placeLongitude;
NSString *radiusOne = @"100";

CLLocationDegrees latTwo = [latOne doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees lngTwo =[lngOne doubleValue];
CLLocationDistance radiusTwo = [radiusOne doubleValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latTwo, lngTwo);
CLRegion *grRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coordinates 
radius:radiusTwo identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"grRegion%i", 1]];

[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:grRegion];
```

**My didEnterRegion is also in the profileViewController**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region 
{
    //local notification code is in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view controller that is set as delegate for your location manager is the one that will implement/respond to didEnter/didExit, I recommend you to use a singelton pattern (or shared instance) of your location manager and to setup de delegate correctly. Several view controller with several location managers can cause problems.